# Split a set of size N into M groups with minimum difference between sums of these groups

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

There is a set of size `N <= 50` of positive numbers. **This set cannot be sorted or changed**!!!

```
S = {n1, n2, n3, ..., nN}
```

I need to split the set `S` on `M <= 25` groups:

```
Groups = {{n1, n2}, {n3, n4, n5...},...,{... nN}} -> len(Groups) = M
```

**The maximum difference between two adjacent groups should be as less as possible.**
Difference is calculated in such way:

```
diff = abs(sum(G1) - sum(G2)) = abs((n1 + n2) - (n3 + n4 + n5))
```

I could generate all vectors of size `N` that contain only `M` non-zero digits (like `1`) but I will be obliged to consider `50! / (25! * 25!)` for brute force that is wrong :(

Example:

```
6, 13, 10, 2
case 1: {6}, {13, 10, 2} -> difference = 25
case 2: {6, 13}, {10, 2} -> difference = 5
case 3: {6, 13, 10}, {2} -> difference = 29
The best case is second -> difference = 5!
```

What an idea can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you use extra space?

Comment: Isn't this just effectively dividing the array into 2 consecutive segments with minimum difference?

Comment: It can be divided not only on 2 but also 3,4, .., M

Comment: But... have you tried an idea from your tags - dynamic programming?

Comment: @MBo Setting up the dynamic programming in this case is easier said than done.  And most people who know about dynamic programming will struggle with producing the actual answer at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with a combination of dynamic programming and a modification of A* search.

```
import heapq

def best_division (numbers, pieces):
    cumulative_sums = [0]
    for number in numbers:
        cumulative_sums.append(cumulative_sums[-1] + number)

    # We need this to be somewhat bigger than the maximum sum.
    # Making it + pieces/2 will result in a better
    # expected_piece_size.
    sum_bound = cumulative_sums[-1] + (pieces // 2)

    # We expect our pieces to be somewhere close to this size.
    expected_piece_size = (cumulative_sums[-1] + (pieces//2)) // pieces

    # This data structure will include:
    #
    #   By completed segments
    #       By start of segment
    #           By end of segment
    #               (lowest maximum difference, prev_start)
    #
    # It will actually be an array of dictionaries of dictionaries.
    #
    # It starts off empty.
    best_path_info = []

    # The queue is a minimum priority queue.
    #
    #   [
    #       lowest maximum difference,
    #       abs(sum of segment - expected_piece_size),
    #       count_pieces,
    #       start,
    #       end,
    #       prev_start
    #   ]
    #
    # This causes us to first look at the lowest maximum difference,
    # and then at the segment sum being close to the expected.
    #
    # It also means we can trace backwards once we have an answer.
    queue = []

    for i in range(len(cumulative_sums)):
        heapq.heappush(
            queue, [
                0,
                abs(cumulative_sums[i] - expected_piece_size),
                0,
                0,
                i,
                None
            ])

    while len(queue):
        max_diff, _, count_completed, start, end, prev_start = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if count_completed + 1 == pieces: # The current piece is not in the count
            if end == len(numbers):
                answer = [numbers[start:end]]
                end = start
                start = prev_start
                while start is not None:
                    answer.append(numbers[start:end])
                    count_completed -= 1
                    prev_start = best_path_info[count_completed][start][end][1]
                    end = start
                    start = prev_start
                ### RETURN HERE ###
                return list(reversed(answer))

            else:
                continue # Not a solution

        if len(best_path_info) <= count_completed:
            best_path_info.append({})

        path = best_path_info[count_completed]
        if start not in path:
            path[start] = {}
        path = path[start]
        if end not in path or max_diff < path[end][0]:
            path[end] = (max_diff, prev_start)
            for next_end in range(end, len(cumulative_sums)):
                this_sum = cumulative_sums[end] - cumulative_sums[start]
                next_sum = cumulative_sums[next_end] - cumulative_sums[end]
                next_max_diff = max(max_diff, abs(next_sum - this_sum))
                heapq.heappush(
                    queue, [
                        next_max_diff,
                        abs(next_sum - expected_piece_size),
                        count_completed + 1,
                        end,
                        next_end,
                        start
                    ])
```

Comment: It's not easy to understand the idea :( but anyway probably there will be no better solution than this)

Comment: @AyratArifullin I can improve the efficiency. But you're best off studying "A* search" and "Dynamic programming" to try to figure it out.